# iCloud photos Windows synchronization of files stalled - how to determine why?

Tags: windows-10, sync, photos, icloud

I have a 50000 element 240 GB photo library in Apples iCloud which I would like to download fully for backup purposes on a Windows 10 machine.  I have installed iCloud from the Microsoft store, and allowed iCloud to finish creation of the local "iCloud photos" folder with 50000 tiny stubs which Windows then download fully if needed.  This appear to work as intended.

I then right-clicked the "iCloud photos" folder and chose "Always keep on this device" after which Windows updated all 50000 entries and started downloading files.

Then at one point the data transfer stopped.  Windows indicates with the green bar going to the right that progress is expected.  Due to the size of the directory Windows is very slow showing changes after I e.g. sort by status.

When I try to download a file explicitly - for instance by clicking on it, I get an error saying:

> An unexpected error prohibits you in copying the file.  If you keep
> getting this error, you can use the error code to search for help for
> this problem.
>
> Error 0x80070185: The requested cloud action failed.

I am an experienced developer, but unfamiliar with this. My gut feeling is that there may be files with problematic names for the Windows synchronizatio mechanism (as the files have originated on MacOS over many years), but I do not have any kind of proof.  This stalling has happened before and this time I tried uninstalling iCloud completely before trying again (and it appears to be working as intended before asking for synchronization).  I have manually moved the "Pictures" folder to D: to get enough space.

I would appreciate pointers towards allowing me to identify what is wrong so I can look into  correcting the files on my Mac (which doesn't have enough space causing this whole exercise).

[image: error dialogue when trying to download]

Comment: I had this issue too. My guess (and it's only a guess) is iCloud throttling downloads for some reason…